# How i can insert a String variable into an Sql statement in java

Tags: java, sql, string, combobox

How can i pass the value from the comboBox to the sql statement?

```
 String name = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
    String sql = "SELECT surname FROM employee WHERE etairia = name ";
    result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String name = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
String sql = "SELECT surname FROM employee WHERE etairia = (?)";
statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql); // conn is Connection
statement.setString(1, name); // '1' is the param index, it's always start from 1, not from zero
result = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: eclipse says statement.setString doesnt exist , what's wrong?

Comment: Do you use index correctly and parameter exsists? The usage of setString is <paramIndex, param>

Comment: i tried it..only bug..about result variable..any idea? what type is it??